# Can someone have a look at my jquery UI autocomplete code and tell me why its only working on 1 textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code that uses jquery ui autocomplete, the problem is I am having difficulty setting up a second autocomplete on the same page. Can someone have a look at the code and let me know whats wrong? The top one runs ok.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        var AccommObject = $("[id$='_txtAccommodation_txtStandard']")[0];
        var Accommid = AccommObject.id;
        var AccommidFull = "#" + Accommid;


        var AccommObject2 = $("[id$='_txtInvoiceNo_txtStandard']")[0];
        var Accommid2 = AccommObject2.id;
        var AccommidFull2 = "#" + Accommid2;



        $(AccommidFull).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "RequisitionSearch.aspx/FetchAccommodationNameList",
                    data: '{"AccommodationName":"' + request.term + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(
                        $.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.ID,
                                label: item.Label,
                                value: item.Value,
                                ImageURL: item.ImageURL
                            };
                        })
                        );
                    },
                    error: function(result) { debugger; }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });



        $(AccommidFull2).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "RequisitionSearch.aspx/FetchAccommodationInvoiceNoList",
                    data: '{"InvoiceNo":"' + request.term + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(
                        $.map(data.d, function(item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.ID,
                                label: item.Label,
                                value: item.Value,
                                ImageURL: item.ImageURL
                            };
                        })
                        );
                    },
                    error: function(result) { debugger; }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });


    });
```

Comment: That's not very specific.  Does it throw a javascript error in the console?

Comment: And can we see the HTML

Comment: Sorry about that, the second one does not have any error as such, it just does not fire the target method. The question is what is the correct way to have multiple instances of autocomplete on the same page. For some reason the event has not been wired up to the second textbox. I have debugged and can see that it is getting the 2nd textbox in exactly the same as the first but its not firing.

Comment: I see this person had exactly the same problem but no remedy.            (https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-jquery-ui-autocomplete-on-same-page)

Comment: The code looks correct to me. Perhaps the second jquery object does not match the element. What does `alert($(AccommidFull2).length);` show? If it is `1`, then check the data that is returned in the `success` callback.

Comment: Im not at work today but I will do this tomorrow, the second ajax call is not firing so at the moment there is no success callback to check, however I will do the other check you suggested.

Comment: Solved this, it was caused be another user control having the same design time ID, when run the two of these controls were being retrieved. So instead of doing $("[id$='_txtInvoiceNo_txtStandard']")[0]; I had to do this $("[id$='_txtInvoiceNo_txtStandard']")[1]; Rrrrrrrrrrrrr!!

Comment: I managed to fix this, the error was happening because it was picking up another element that had the same name on a user control. So all I had to do was change the index from [0] to [1]. Very frustrating! But thanks to everyone here who contributed and assured me the code was correct, which it was really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a really annoying one!

The part $("[id$='_txtAccommodation_txtStandard']")[0] was using the zero index object but there was a user control on the form that contained another textbox with exactly the same extension so all I had to do was refer to $("[id$='_txtAccommodation_txtStandard']")[1] and the problem was solved!

```
var AccommObject = $("[id$='_txtAccommodation_txtStandard']")[0];
        var Accommid = AccommObject.id;
        var AccommidFull = "#" + Accommid;


        var AccommObject2 = $("[id$='_txtInvoiceNo_txtStandard']")[0];
        var Accommid2 = AccommObject2.id;
        var AccommidFull2 = "#" + Accommid2;
```